# How can I change model attributes in Strapi cli?

Tags: strapi

I accidently typed a duplicate name while creating attributes in Dish model in Strapi. I was a newbie, so I was working on Strapi admin interface, but since I got a duplicate name issue, `strapi start` doesn't work but show the below error message.

> ➜  backend strapi start
>   [2019-06-28T19:37:16.971Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
>   [2019-06-28T19:37:16.972Z] error ALTER TABLE `dishes` ADD `Restaurant` integer  NULL ; - SQLITE_ERROR: duplicate column name: Restaurant

Due to the issue, I can't start Strapi which means I can't access the GUI admin. Is there a way to change or remove attributes in Strapi cli?

Answer (score 0):

based documentation of strapi

```
strapi generate:model <name>
Generates an empty model called <name> in the ./api/<name>/models folder. It will create two files. The first one will be <name>.js which contains your lifecycle callbacks and another <name>.settings.json that will list your attributes and options.
```

I think you must goto `<name>.settings.json` file and **remove** duplicate attribute  in editor.
[read more](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-alpha.x/cli/CLI.html#strapi-generate-model)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to solve this problem is to go to the folder api located in your strapi project (/path/to/your/strapiproject/api).

Then remove the correspondant model or entity which cause the problem.

If you restart, your server will succesfully launch.

Then joy creating again the model by using the way you want (standard way with the site or cli).